# push notification when app is close wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

I am trying to receive a push notification in Windows Phone Silver light 8.1 app, I have learn through [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx) Example. It's work fine when app is running but when I close the app at that time, it is not receiving a notification, or might be not able to display a toast notification.

When app is running at that time notification displayed in a Message Box, so the problem I face is toast notification. Is there any hidden code for Toast Notification?

It was working fine earlier but after some time it automatically stopped displaying toast notification.

Please Help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
toast.Title = "[title]";
toast.Content = "[content]";
toast.Show();
```

Check this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx
Also you have to make sure your app is allowed to run in background, and make sure that it can run in background.

Comment: In my app if I set location Latitude 72.336655 and Longitude 166.225588 [For Example], when user reach at the same place at that time if my app is not working than also I wants to remind user using toast notification.

Comment: well then get geo coordinates from gps and check if they are the same as the one you set, and make toast :)